# Как сверстать нестандартный блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какими способами можно сверстать каплю снизу блока чтобы в ней был background-image блока?
Интересует несколько возможных решений

Comment: SVG, clip-path, mask, просто background-image.. Выбирайте.

Comment: _"Интересует несколько возможных решений"_ Интересует несколько ваших попыток решения.

Comment: первые размышления начались с использования псевдоэлементов, сейчас играюсь с clip-path, пока что желаемого результата добиться не получается :с

Comment: как я понял, добиться желаемого закругления просто используя встроенные возможности (circle, polygon...) в clip-path у меня не получиться, жаль нельзя например в полигон вложить на какое-то место circle. Получается мне нужно использовать SVG в clip-path, но любая попытка сделать это растягивает SVG до некорректных размеров (пробовал засунуть path svg в clip-path: path(...).

Comment: думаю тут ты можешь найти ответ. https://html5book.ru/nestandartnye-bloki-na-sayte/
а я после работы покапаюсь. тема интересная)

Comment: Я бы картинкой загрузил, так как вам кроме того, что нужно сделать каплю, ещё нужно будет к ней применить тень. А при clip-path вроде не получится потом тень навесить в форме капли.

Comment: @ptrv-dev: _"пробовал засунуть..."_ Хотелось бы не на словах, но в коде. Ибо, разумение наше конкретики требует, а лясы точить, да Емелей с печей снимать - не под стать сообществу здешнему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мужик, смотри. Увидел, что ты уже с этим мучался).

```html
<body>
  <svg class="img">
      <mask id="circle">
        <rect fill="white" cx="100" cy="100" width="800" height="300"></rect>
        <circle fill="white" cx="400" cy="300" r="100"></circle>
       
      </mask>
      <g mask="url(#circle)">
        <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" width="100%" xlink:href="1.jpg"></image>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <div class="gg"></div>
</body>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(./2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

svg {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

.gg {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Смысл такой: берем контейнер SVG, в него помещаем mask с айди, на который мы будем ссылаться в нашей картинке. Помещаем 2 объекта rect - прямоугольник, circle - круг. Размещаем их по осям  x y и выставляем им размеры. Далее в  ставим нашу картинку. Для наглядности создал еще один див.

Может быть я и плохо объяснил, может быть не точь-в-точь как в твоем примере, Но получился отдельный блок необычной формы. От сюда можно уже плясать.

Comment: Пока что этот вариант дал мне наиболее подходящий результат, пока игрался с clip-path тоже получал результат очень похожий на макет, но его было невозможно адаптировать. Сейчас буду пытаться адаптировать Ваш вариант, спасибо!